# Accessing a node in code using Verilog define macros

Tags: string, parameters, macros, verilog

Is their a possibility to access a node in the code using a define macro via string parameters

e.g.

```
module design
  (
   input logic signal_in_1_temp,
   input logic signal_in_2_temp
   );
endmodule

module tb_top;

   parameter string signal_names[0:1] = {"in_1","in_2"};

   i_design design(.signal_in_1_temp(0),.signal_in_2_temp(0));

   `define IN_SIG(IN_NAME,VAL)\

   force i_design.signal_\``IN_NAME\``_temp = VAL; 

   initial begin
      \`IN_SIG(signal_name[0],1);
      \`IN_SIG(signal_name[1],0);
   end

endmodule
```

In the above the two inputs of the design would need to be accessed via a parameter list and then a macro ...

Compiling the above gives error .... I would want to know if we can access the nodes status or drive them based on the above means ..

The idea is to have a dynamic parameter list given and then to know the status of that list or drive them based on need....

Any suggestions ... please

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use string names within the language to build identifier names. Verilog does have a C interface (called VPI) that allows you to access signals by signal name, but that comes at a performance cost which means the signal cannot have certain optimizations and must remain intact.

SystemVerilog has a `bind` construct that allows you to attach functionality to signals deep inside your design. I wrote a [DVCon paper](http://events.dvcon.org/2012/proceedings/papers/01P_3.pdf) about it.

Comment: Can i use a C VPI to do this .. basically a C function which is provided with the name as a string and then it returns over its assigned value ... ? any reference for that .. ?

Comment: https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/resources/overview/introspection-into-systemverilog-without-turning-it-inside-out-08587fce-0e73-400f-b2f6-0bbd6a2fe746

Comment: @MayurAnvekar vpi can use strings to access elements by name. So, in c/c++ you can build strings dynamically (using strcpy, std:string, ...). You can also build strings dynamically in system verilog and pass them to as argument to a vpi or a dpi function to access your variables (it is difficult to do in v95/v2k though).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do it with strings, but you can do it with regular macro arguments.

here is a working example:

```
`define A(B) \
$display(sig_``B``_sig);

module top;
  logic sig_x_sig, sig_hello_sig;

  initial begin
    `A(x)
    `A(hello)
  end
endmodule
```

do not use `\` as in your code and do not use empty lines in macro definitions.

Comment: Every close .. possibly i should try to do this as you mentioned ... thanks .. let me see if some improvements can be done ...